# Kivy - Optimization For Hand-Helds (Android, IOS, etc)

Tags: android, optimization, kivy, frame-rate

I'm always worried about optimization when it comes to game design and need to ask more experienced kivy users about some concerns.

Which one is truly faster?

Lets say you stored your graphic instructions in class attributes.  If you're going to have a number of graphics updating on the screen every frame, but you're not adding or taking away from the canvas, Ask_Update seems to be the qualified choice.

Lets say you do add and remove graphic pieces around enough.  Would it be better to just Clear the Canvas and canvas.add the stored instructions back?

or

Would it be better to call Clear after every removal or addition?  That would seem like a pain in the tail vs just Clearing and canvas.add the graphics back.

Vectors....

How optimized are Vectors?  Is the function/method a slow process?  Just wondering because I've used 3D engines in the past that had some slow calls and it's usually the mathematical ones.

What is considered a good frame rate for a game app running on a hand-held device?

I also wonder about deleting instances.  Does kivy have some special call for deleting an instance or would the usual del call (after running a cleanup function) and python garbage collection be enough?

I'm researching now because I don't want to develop something only to realize I wasn't aware of Kivy 'dos-and-donts'.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the canvas is inefficient, don't do that unless you actually want to remove everything.

You don't need to call ask_update in general.

Kivy's Vectors aren't particularly optimised, they're just wrappers around lists, but this probably isn't actually a problem for you.

A good framerate target is 60fps.

You can look at [KivEnt](http://kivent.org/) for a game engine with particularly good performance with Kivy.

Comment: I ran a test and found out that not clearing the canvas causes a frame rate crash.  If you think about how 3D engines work, each frame is drawn anew, thus clearing the last frame drawn.  The same logic is followed when clearing the canvas and redrawing.  All you're doing is building the scene graph...sending what needs to be drawn to the gpu and not sending anything that doesn't need to be drawn at all in the next frame (like dead monsters being removed).  By not clearing the canvas you're leaving the last frame contents there, which would explain the frame rate crash.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't clear the canvas but did add new things to it each frame. Don't do that, update the existing canvas objects that are already added  to the canvas.

Comment: And if you want to add/remove objects, add or remove those specific objects, not everything at once. When you do this you force everything to be recalculated on the cpu and passed to the gpu again, which is exactly what you don't want to happen.